# Form is not Deleting Column Data from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

I have a PHP Form that should allow the user to delete an image from the folder `images`. The image is pulled by calling the name of the image from the MySQL Table's column `photo`. When the user submits the form, the image should be deleted from the `images` folder, and the data in the column `photo` in the MySQL Table should have it's value blanked out.

Currently, the form deletes the image from the `images` folder, but doesn't change the value of the `photo` column. For example, if the user were to delete the image `dog.jpg` using the form, the `photo` column's value would be changed from `dog.jpg` to . The actual image would also be deleted from the `images` folder.

Here is the full PHP page's code:

```
<?php
// delete an image
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
  $identification = $_POST['identify'];
  $filename1 = $_POST['deletecolumndata'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    "UPDATE used_trailers ".
    "SET photo = '' ".
       "WHERE id = $identification" ;
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
}

// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('dsom', 'ssm', 'Ksr', 'ksm');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `used_trailers`';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);

// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
    // Make sure there are some files in there
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
    }
    else {
        // Print the top of a table
        echo '<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                    <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                    <td><b>Created</b></td>
                    <td><b>Title</b></td>
                    <td><b>Description</b></td>
                    <td><b>Model</b></td>
                    <td><b>Make</b></td>
                    <td><b>Year</b></td>
                    <td><b>Price</b></td>
                    <td><b>Photo 1</b></td>
                    <td><b>Photo 2</b></td>
                    <td><b>Photo 3</b></td>
                    <td><b>Photo 4</b></td>
                    <td><b>Photo 5</b></td>
                    <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                </tr>';

        // Print each file
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['title']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['description']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['model']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['make']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['year']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['price']}</td>
                    <td><img src=images/{$row['photo']}></td>
                    <form method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' value='{$row['id']}' name='identify' />
                    <input type='hidden' value='images/{$row['photo']}' name='delete_file'/>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='deletecolumndata' />
<input type='submit' value='Delete image' />
</form>
                    <td><img src=images/{$row['photo1']}></td>
                    <td><img src=images/{$row['photo2']}></td>
                    <td><img src=images/{$row['photo3']}></td>
                    <td><img src=images/{$row['photo4']}></td>
                    <td><a target='_blank' href='downloadfile.php?id={$row['id']}'>View PDF</a></td>
                </tr>";
        }

        // Close table
        echo '</table>';
    }

    // Free the result
    $result->free();
}
else
{
    echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
    echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
}

// Close the mysql connection
$dbLink->close();
?>
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM used_trailers WHERE id = '{$identification}'`...

Comment: `"UPDATE used_trailers ".
    "SET photo = '' ".
       "WHERE id = $identification" ;` is a pure string, not assigned to any variable, neither used. You just do not execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing the UPDATE query.
Instead of just specifying the string like

```
    "UPDATE used_trailers ".
    "SET photo = '' ".
    "WHERE id = $identification" ;
```

Try

```
$sql = "UPDATE used_trailers ".
       "SET photo = '' ".
       "WHERE id = $identification" ;

$dbLink = new mysqli('dsom', 'ssm', 'Ksr', 'ksm');
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you, got it working by executing the update query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "UPDATE used_trailers ".
    "SET photo = '' ".
       "WHERE id = $identification" ;
```

This query is flying in the air but doing nothing right now. You need to establish mysql connection and query it the way you query `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM used_trailers';`

Answer (score 0):

i see a lot of mistakes.
First your SQL UPDATE query does not get executed. It is just a string.
Even if you would execute it, I doubt you would have the desired effect. Because your SELECT query does not have a where clause where it checks for hte photo coloumn.

So either change the UPDATE query into a DELETE query (and make sure it gets executed) 
or change the WHERE clause of your SELECT query

so to add some code, either do this:

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET photo = '' WHERE id = $identification" ;
$result = $dbLink->query($updatesql);
```

and then change your SELECT query into this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM used_trailers WHERE photo <> ''";
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
```

OR change your UPDATE into:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM used_trailers WHERE id = $identification" ;
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
```

and thats it, nothing else should get changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed to execute the `update` query.

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET photo = '' WHERE id = $identification" ;
$result = $dbLink->query($updatesql);
```

instead of

```
 "UPDATE used_trailers ".
"SET photo = '' ".
   "WHERE id = $identification" ;
```